# Magento: Invalid Attribute Name error

Tags: magento

I'm trying to get all the products stored under a certain category.

Everything is working fine writing:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addCategoryFilter($category)
                ->setOrder('position', 'DESC')
                ->load();
```

I've got all the products correctly sorted by their position attribute.
Since some of them don't have any position set, I want to exclude them, so I tried simply:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addCategoryFilter($category)
                ->addFieldToFilter( 'position', array('gt'=>0) )
                ->setOrder('position', 'DESC')
                ->load();
```

But the page can't be loaded, I get an error 'There has been an error processing your request' and an error log is stored under var/report starting with

> a:5:{i:0;s:33:"Invalid attribute name: position.

And I cannot figure out to solve this .. I googled a lot and tried a lot of solutions, but no one worked.
I cannot understand why it accepts an attribut for sorting while not for filtering.

Any idea?


EDITED:
The query performed by $products is

```
SELECT
    `e`.*,
    `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`,
    `price_index`.`price`,
    `price_index`.`tax_class_id`,
    `price_index`.`final_price`,
    IF(`price_index`.`tier_price`, LEAST(`price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`),
    `price_index`.`min_price`) AS `minimal_price`,
    `price_index`.`min_price`,
    `price_index`.`max_price`,
    `price_index`.`tier_price`

FROM
    `tb_catalog_product_entity` AS `e`

INNER JOIN
    `tb_catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index`
ON
    cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id
AND
    cat_index.store_id='3'
AND
    cat_index.category_id='2476'
AND
    cat_index.is_parent=1

INNER JOIN
    `tb_catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index`
ON
    price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id
AND
    price_index.website_id = '1'
AND
    price_index.customer_group_id = 0

ORDER BY
    `cat_index_position` ASC,
    `cat_index`.`product_id` ASC
```

I tried also:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addCategoryFilter($category)
            ->addFieldToFilter( 'cat_index_position', 'notnull' )
            ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
            ->load();
```

with same result:

```
Invalid attribute name: cat_index_position.";i:1;s:4700:"#0 /path/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1155): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Invalid attribu...')
```

**EDITED:**
I think my problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434971/after-join-cannot-filter-by-attribute-qty-getting-products-from-inventory-tha)
but I cannot figure out how to solve it!

**EDITED:**

Tried also

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('cat_index_position')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('cat_index_position', array('gt'=>'0'));
```

Always the same error

**EDITED:**

If I add

```
WHERE `position` > 0
```

In my query browser it's working!
So how can I add it to my query within magento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I solved in this way:

**1)** Modified
app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php

```
~line 384
if (empty($attributeInstance)
|| !($attributeInstance instanceof Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract)
|| (!$attributeInstance->getId() && !in_array($attributeInstance->getAttributeCode(), $this->getDefaultAttributes()))
) {
    return false;
}
```

to

```
if (empty($attributeInstance)
|| !($attributeInstance instanceof Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract)
// || (!$attributeInstance->getId() && !in_array($attributeInstance->getAttributeCode(), $this->getDefaultAttributes()))
) {
    return false;
}
```

**2)** Modified
app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php

```
~line 1237
if ($entity->isAttributeStatic($attribute)) {
    $conditionSql = $this->_getConditionSql('e.'.$attribute, $condition);
} else {
....
```

to

```
if ($entity->isAttributeStatic($attribute)) {
    $conditionSql = $this->_getConditionSql('e.'.$attribute, $condition);

    $attributeInstance = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
                            ->getAttribute($this->getAttribute($attribute)->getEntityType(), $attribute);

    if (!$attributeInstance->getId() && !in_array($attributeInstance->getAttributeCode(), $this->getAttribute($attribute)->getDefaultAttributes()))
    {
        // die( "FOUND".$attribute );
        $conditionSql = $this->_getConditionSql($attribute, $condition);
    }

} else {
...
```

**And finally** I can get my collection filtered by position:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addCategoryFilter($category)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('position', array('gt'=>'0'))
            ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
            ->load();
```

**Note:**
Obviously it's better to override previous core files rather than modifying them directly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
->addFieldToFilter( 'position', 'notnull' )
```

For more informations, have a look [there](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento-tutorials/addattributetofilter-conditionals-in-magento)

Comment: It doesn't work as well. :( I already knew that link however thanks for sharing :)

Comment: We don't have the addAttributeToFilter here, this query is not really useful. Can you display it with it (don't load the collection so you shouldn't have any error)

Comment: Simply writing $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addCategoryFilter($category)->addFieldToFilter( 'position', 'notnull' ); WILL produce error here, sorry :( (Invalid attribute name: position) ... the query I wrote is removing the addFieldToFilter part you're right ...

Comment: I think my problem is similar to this on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434971/after-join-cannot-filter-by-attribute-qty-getting-products-from-inventory-tha but I cannot figure out how to solve it

Comment: AddFieldToFilter is for a lower layer of database model interaction, whereas AddAttributeToFilter is higher up, dealing with the EAV system only...

Comment: I made it work .. have a look to my answerhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947236/magento-invalid-attribute-name-error/10030839#10030839 .. I wouldn't wish to change core codes but I had no other choice.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved by adding:

```
$products->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft( array('category_product_index'=>Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->getTable('catalog/category_product_index')), '`e`.`entity_id` = `category_product_index`.`product_id`', array('position AS cat_index_position'))
            ->group('e.entity_id');
```